# Как пишется "мелко нарезанный"?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Как пишется "мелко нарезанный": посыпать мелко нарезанной зеленью?

Answer (score 5):

Словосочетания, состоящие из наречия и прилагательного, пишутся раздельно: **гладко выбритый, мелко порезанный, остро наточенный.**

Слитно пишутся сложные прилагательные, которые употребляются как термины или в составе терминологических выражений. Первая часть таких прилагательных представлена наречным словом на о или е, вторая — прилагательным или причастием:

> Напр.: **быстродействующий,высокооплачиваемый, глубокосидящий, глубокоуважаемый,малоактивный, малоблагоприятный, маловажный, маловероятный, маловирулентный ('почти неспособный вызвать заболевания'), маловразумительный, малограмотный,**

См.: Валгина Н.С., Светлышева В.Н. Орфография и пунктуация: справочник.- М.: "Неолит", 2001